# Implementacion de shared y weak ptr

Tags: c++

Esta es mi implementacion de los punteros inteligentes. Los estuve probando y no encontré ningun problema, pero me vendría bien que me lo comenten si encuntran algo raro, algo que mejorar o cualquier tipo de opinion, aunque no sea algo que corregir.

Tambien querria hacer una version que sea thread safe, pero no estoy tan seguro de como la puedo implementar, asi que tambien busco sugerencias para eso.

Paso con la implementacion:

-Estas son clases que componen a sPtr y a wPtr(shared y weak ptr):

```
struct CtrlBlock{
    unsigned int sharedCount;
    unsigned int weakCount;
    CtrlBlock():sharedCount(1),weakCount(1){}
    virtual void release()=0;
    virtual ~CtrlBlock(){}
};
template<typename T>
struct Block_pointer:public CtrlBlock{
    T* ptr;
    Block_pointer(T* p):ptr(p){}
    void release()override{delete ptr;}
    ~Block_pointer()override{}
};
template<typename T>
struct Block_object:public CtrlBlock{
    char obj[sizeof(T)];
    template<typename... Args>
    Block_object(Args&& ... args){new(obj)T(args...);}
    void release()override{(*((T*)obj)).~T();}
    ~Block_object()override{}
};
template<typename T>
class smart_ptr{
    protected:
        CtrlBlock* ctrl_block;
        T* data;
        smart_ptr(CtrlBlock* control_block,T* dat):ctrl_block(control_block),data(dat){}
    public:
        T& operator*()const{
            return *data;
        }
        T* operator->()const{
            return data;
        }
        bool operator==(const smart_ptr<T>& other)const{
            return this->data==other.data;
        }
        bool operator!=(const smart_ptr<T>& other)const{
            return this->data!=other.data;
        }
        bool operator<=(const smart_ptr<T>& other)const{
            return this->data<=other.data;
        }
        bool operator>=(const smart_ptr<T>& other)const{
            return this->data>=other.data;
        }
        bool operator<(const smart_ptr<T>& other)const{
            return this->data<other.data;
        }
        bool operator>(const smart_ptr<T>& other)const{
            return this->data>other.data;
        }
};
```

-La clase de **shared_ptr:**

```
template<typename T>
class sPtr:public smart_ptr<T>{
    template<typename D> friend class sPtr;
    private:
        void release_ownership(){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr){//    El puntero actual deja de apuntar a la memoria de la que era dueño, si esta no tiene mas dueños se libera
                if((--this->ctrl_block->sharedCount)==0){   //Si sharedCount llega a 0 borra la memoria a la que apunta
                    this->ctrl_block->release();
                    if(--this->ctrl_block->weakCount==0)    //Solo borra el contador de referencias si weakCount tambien es 0. En caso de que 
                        delete this->ctrl_block;        //weakCount no sea 0, ctrl_block no se borrara y el destructor del wPtr que lo mantiene vivo se ocupara de esto
                }
            }
        }
    public:
        template<typename D>
        sPtr(const wPtr<D>& weakPtr):smart_ptr<T>(weakPtr.ctrl_block,weakPtr.data){
            if(weakPtr.ctrl_block==nullptr or weakPtr.ctrl_block.sharedCount==0)
                this->ctrl_block=nullptr;
            else
                this->ctrl_block->sharedCount++;
        }
        sPtr():smart_ptr<T>(nullptr,nullptr){}
        sPtr(const sPtr& other):smart_ptr<T>(other.ctrl_block,other.data){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)   //Si no declaro este constructor lo declara de forma implicita y prefiere llamarlo antes que a la version template, lo que genera errores.
                this->ctrl_block->sharedCount++;
        }
        sPtr(T* dat):smart_ptr<T>(nullptr,dat){
            if(dat!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block=new Block_pointer<T>(dat);
        }
        template<typename D>
        sPtr(const sPtr<D>& other):smart_ptr<T>(other.ctrl_block,other.data){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->sharedCount++;
        }
        template<typename D>
        sPtr(D* dat):smart_ptr<T>(nullptr,dat){
            if(dat!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block=new Block_pointer<D>(dat);
        }
        template<typename D>
        sPtr(sPtr<D>&& other):smart_ptr<T>(other.ctrl_block,other.data){
            other.data=nullptr;
            other.ctrl_block=nullptr;
        }
        void operator=(const sPtr& other){  //Con este pasa lo mismo que con el constructor de copia, asi que tambien lo tengo que declarar
            this->release_ownership();
            this->data=other.data;
            this->ctrl_block=other.ctrl_block;
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->sharedCount++;
        }
        template<typename D>
        void operator=(const sPtr<D>& other){
            this->release_ownership();
            this->data=other.data;
            this->ctrl_block=other.ctrl_block;
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->sharedCount++;
        }
        template<typename D>
        void operator=(D* dat){
            this->release_ownership();
            smart_ptr<T>::data=dat;
            if(dat!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block=new Block_pointer<D>(dat);
            else
                this->ctrl_block=nullptr;
        }
        template<typename D>
        void operator=(sPtr<D>&& other){
            if(this==&other)
                return;
            this->release_ownership();
            this->data=other.data;
            this->ctrl_block=other.ctrl_block;
            other.data=nullptr;
            other.ctrl_block=nullptr;
        }
        unsigned int currentOwners()const{
            return this->ctrl_block==nullptr? 0 : this->ctrl_block->sharedCount;
        }
        ~sPtr(){
            release_ownership();
        }
        template<typename A,typename ...Args>friend sPtr<A> make_sPtr(Args&& ...args);
};
template<typename T,typename ...Args>
sPtr<T> make_sPtr(Args&& ...args){
    sPtr<T> ptr;
    ptr.ctrl_block=new Block_object<T>(args...);
    ptr.data=((T*)((Block_object<T>*)ptr.ctrl_block)->obj);
    return ptr;
}
```

-**weak_ptr:**

```
template<typename T>
class wPtr:public smart_ptr<T>{
    friend class sPtr<T>;
    public:
        wPtr():smart_ptr<T>(nullptr){}
        wPtr(const wPtr<T>& other):smart_ptr<T>(other.ctrl_block,other.data){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->weakCount++;
        }
        template<typename D>
        wPtr(const wPtr<D>& other):smart_ptr<T>(other.ctrl_block,other.data){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->weakCount++;
        }
        template<typename D>
        wPtr(const sPtr<D>& other):smart_ptr<T>(other.ctrl_block,other.data){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->weakCount++;
        }
        void operator=(const wPtr<T>& other){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr){
                if(--this->ctrl_block->weakCount==0)
                    delete this->ctrl_block;
            }
            this->ctrl_block=other.ctrl_block;
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->weakCount++;
        }
        template<typename D>
        void operator=(const wPtr<D>& other){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr){
                if(--this->ctrl_block->weakCount==0)
                    delete this->ctrl_block;
            }
            this->ctrl_block=other.ctrl_block;
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->weakCount++;
        }
        template<typename D>
        void operator=(const sPtr<D>& other){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr){
                if(--this->ctrl_block->weakCount==0)
                    delete this->ctrl_block;
            }
            this->ctrl_block=other.ctrl_block;
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr)
                this->ctrl_block->weakCount++;
        }
        unsigned int currentOwners(){
            return this->ctrl_block==nullptr? 0 : this->ctrl_block->sharedCount;
        }
        bool alive(){
            return this->ctrl_block!=nullptr and this->ctrl_block->sharedCount>0;
        }
        ~wPtr(){
            if(this->ctrl_block!=nullptr){
                if(--this->ctrl_block->weakCount==0)
                    delete this->ctrl_block;
            }
        }
};
```